# CQ5 Library Component Duplicating, Not Overwriting in Apps folder

Tags: adobe, aem

When you clone a default component in the libs folder to your apps one, it's supposed to override the former, but for me it's duplicating the component's options in the sidekick.

I made a duplicate of **libs/foundation/components/parsys/** and moved it to **apps/-site-/components/content** so that I could add functionality to it.  However, when I view the Columns component in the sidekick (which is the */parsys/colctrl/* component) it duplicates my options. I now have "Two Columns", "Three Columns", and "Column Control" list twice.

Ideas?

Comment: change the jcr:title of the components in /apps, if you want to inherit as a new component change your sling:resourceSuperType, you can overlay like what antonyh mentioned

Answer (score 3):

To override the stock component (instead of create a new component with the same functionality) you have to have the same path but with /apps instead of /libs

Example for parsys - copy it from

/libs/foundation/components/parsys

to

/apps/foundation/components/parsys

An even better way is to create a new component at /apps/foundation/components/parsys and only override the parts you want to change.

If you change the path, you're basically creating a new component - CQ5 has no way of associating the two. It works on a path basis to overlay the /apps on top of /libs.

Hope this helps,
Antony

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the sidekick's Design Mode to remove the foundation components from the list of candidate components for your pages.  See Gabriel Walt's answer to this question: [Adobe CQ5's sidekick is empty (no components shown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072242/adobe-cq5s-sidekick-is-empty-no-components-shown).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've duplicated the component it shows up twice in sidekick -- but you can add the duplicate to a different component group other than "general".    In the .content.xml file for the component add  componentGroup="Your Component Group"  and your component will then show up  there; the original will still show in the general component group.